# How to escape SagePay values in PHP?

Tags: php, opayo

Before encryption, the string you send to SagePay is formatted like a URL.

```
...&Amount=99.99&Description=An order from My Company...
```

What seems to be missing from the documentation is how to escape these values. I'm stripping out invalid characters per the integration guide but am wondering about special characters that could be in the data sent from the online shop (e.g. ampersands in product names).

To make it bulletproof should I be using `htmlspecialchars`, `htmlentites` or `urlencode` on these values? The only critical thing I can see is to strip colons from the basket string since this is used as a separator. There seems to be no way to escape it.

I've been using 2.23 but am upgrading now to 3.00. Other than the encryption function (it now uses proper AES with padding and CBC) it seems like you can keep the old code.

Comment: You're sending it as a `GET` request, so [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) maybe?

Comment: You don't need to escape any of the values in the crypt string (apart from the basket). Just leave the code as it was, but with AES encryption and VPSProtocol=3.00

Comment: @Rik Blacow Should HTML values be escaped using htmlspecialchars, htmlentites or urlencode? I've asked Sage but they didn't answer the question; they just sent me the integration guide which doesn't fully cover this.

Comment: No. Don't escape them at all. If you do, Sage Pay will bork and give you a '3087 : The SuccessURL format is invalid.'

Comment: @Rik Blacow Thanks. For the basket and description (both HTML fields) do you escape with `htmlspecialchars`, `htmlentites` or `urlencode`? I can see now that other than HTML fields there are no fields that allow ampersand and equals so I guess that's how they get round avoiding it being malformed. Why they can't just let you build it like a normal URL I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't generally use baskets, but I just did a quick check on ampersand in the description field - if you leave it unencoded, it renders fine on the payment pages and in My Sage Pay.

Comment: I did that too; I just find it odd there's no guidance on it — and Sage seems to have lost interest in answering the question (shame as their support is usually good). I guess the answer is: *there are no standards in place, don't escape anything, just filter out invalid chars per the integration guide*. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you do a search for "arrayToQueryString" in the php integration kit, you can see they don't use encoding unless the intention is to send the data to a browser as a redirect header.  They must at least have some kind of bespoke decoding scheme in use on their servers.  It probably ignores equals and ampersand characters with trailing spaces. @SagePaySupport